# From a cylindrical drum containing oil and kept vertical

Tags: calculus, derivatives

From a cylindrical drum containing oil and kept vertical, the oil is leaking so that the level of the oil is decreasing at the rate of $2$cm/min. If the radius and the height of the drum are $10.5$cm and $40$cm respectively, find the rate at which the volume of the oil is decreasing.

My Attempt:

Given
$\textrm {radius} (r)=10.5$cm

$\textrm {height} (h)=40$cm

$\dfrac {dh}{dt}=-2$ cm/min

Also,
$V=\pi r^2h$
$\dfrac {dv}{dt}=\pi(2r.\dfrac {dr}{dt} h+r^2\dfrac {dh}{dt})$

Comment: You're on the right track, if the drum is cylindrical what do you know about $\frac{dr}{dt}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Is the radius of the oil column changing?

If not, then $\frac{dr}{dt}=0$ gives from your equations
$$\dfrac {dV}{dt}=\pi r^2\dfrac {dh}{dt}$$

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: I've used $\dfrac {dh}{dt}=-2$ but the book has used it as $\dfrac {dh}{dt}=2$. which one is correct?

Comment: it should definitely be $-2$, unless $h$ is the height of the empty space in the drum...

Comment: @TonyS.F., Thanks for the explanation